# Fix Ajax call not binding the result to a HTML id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am writing some jQuery and Java code that sends an ajax call to my Java backend to do a procedure and then sends the results back to my jQuery. However, when I run a debug I notice that the information is being sent from Java to jQuery successfully, the issue is the jQuery is cutting off the remaing words after the first space. Below is my code and the result.

**Jquery:**

```
function fillInGPData() {

                        $.ajax({
                            type : "POST",
                            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            dataType : 'json',
                            url : "/ajax/getGPdata",
                            data : JSON.stringify(""),
                            success : function(result) {

                                console.log("Result Selector: " + result);
                                console.log(result == null);

                                $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
                                    console.log("Object: " + obj);
                                    console.log("Tier: " + obj.tier);
                                    console.log( "Selname: " + obj.selname);
                                    console.log("Query: " + obj.query);
                                    console.log("Description: " + obj.description);
                                    console.log("Comment: " + obj.comments);

                                    $(".tableBody1").append(
                                            "<tr id=" + obj.selname + ">"
                                                    + "<td class='sm-width-td'>"
                                                    + obj.selname + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                                });

                            },
                            error : function(err) {

                                console.log(err);

                            }

                        });
                    }
```

**Result:**

```
<tr id="Windows" file="" share=""><td class="sm-width-td">Windows File Share</td></tr>
```

So its the `obj.selname` that is giving the issue. For example, if I pass `Windows File Server`, it will only show `Windows` for the ID. That where the problem is. I just need help figuring out why that is the case.

Comment: `id` should not have spaces, so `Windows File Share` will be cutted to `Windows`, it's not about jQuery, its about HTML specs. My suggestion: `obj.selname.replace(/ /g, '')`

Comment: @CalvinNunes I made an edit to the question for the HTML result and here is the result I get when I colsole.log()      -> ```Selname: Windows File Share```